# Split string into two variables - getting undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, split

I'm using a for loop with a foreach loop inside. In the foreach loop, I get the information I need and echo it to a string like this: `19:00^-2,2° C`. I want to put the time (`19:00`) in one variable and the temperature (`-2,2° C`) in another variable so I can use them to [the chart](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart). But I don't know how I can splice these two. Here's how it looks like at the moment:

```
var yr = localStorage.yr.split('|');
time = yr[16].split('~');
temp = time.split('^');

lineChartData = {
    labels: time,

    datasets: [{
        label: "My Second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: temp
    }]
}
```

With this code, I get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on `temp = time.split('^');`. `yr[16]` prints the following:

`19:00^-2,2° C~20:00^-2° C~21:00^-2° C~22:00^-1,9° C~23:00^-1,6° C~00:00^-1,5° C~01:00^-1,3° C~02:00^-1,1° C~03:00^-0,9° C~04:00^-0,9° C~05:00^-1,1° C~06:00^-1,3° C~07:00^-1,6° C~`

Here's how the PHP code looks like:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 13; $i++) {
    $datetime           = date('Y-m-d\TH', strtotime('+'.$i.' hour'));
    $forecast_period    = $forecast->xpath('(//product/time[contains(@datatype, "forecast")][contains(@from, "'.$datetime.':00:00Z")][contains(@to, "'.$datetime.':00:00Z")])');

    foreach($forecast_period AS $period) {
        $period_datetime                    = date('H:i', strtotime($period->attributes()->from));
        $period_temperature             = $period->location->temperature->attributes()->value;
        $period_temperature_dewpoint        = $period->location->dewpointTemperature->attributes()->value;
        $period_temperature_unit            = $period->location->temperature->attributes()->unit;
        $period_wind_direction              = $period->location->windDirection->attributes()->name;
        $period_wind_direction_degrees      = $period->location->windDirection->attributes()->deg;
        $period_wind_speed                  = $period->location->windSpeed->attributes()->mps;
        $period_fog                     = $period->location->fog->attributes()->percent;
        $period_cloudiness                  = $period->location->cloudiness->attributes()->percent;
        $period_cloudiness_low              = $period->location->lowClouds->attributes()->percent;
        $period_cloudiness_medium           = $period->location->mediumClouds->attributes()->percent;
        $period_cloudiness_high         = $period->location->highClouds->attributes()->percent;
        $period_pressure                    = $period->location->pressure->attributes()->value;
        $period_pressure_unit               = $period->location->pressure->attributes()->unit;
        $period_humidity                    = $period->location->humidity->attributes()->value;

        echo $period_datetime.'^'.temp($period_temperature, $period_temperature_unit, 'not-normal').'~';
    }
}
```

I am getting information from [YR's API](http://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.9/documentation) via `simplexml_load_file()` (`$forecast` is the one who gets the XML data from the API using `simplexml_load_file()`).

With that said, here's my question: How can I put the time and the temperature from `yr[16]` into two variables without getting any errors and therefore build the chart?

Comment: You do know you could simply use JSON?

Comment: `time` is an array. `split()` has to be used on a string, not an array.

Comment: What are you expecting to get into `temp`? There are 13 times and temperatures in `time`.

Comment: @Barmar Oh. I didn't think about that. I changed `temp = time.spl...` to `temp = yr[16].spl...` and it outputs this: `["20:00", "-2° C~21:00", "-2° C~22:00", "-1,9° C~23:00", "-1,6° C~00:00", "-1,5° C~01:00", "-1,3° C~02:00", "-1,1° C~03:00", "-0,9° C~04:00", "-0,9° C~05:00", "-1,1° C~06:00", "-1,3° C~07:00", "-1,6° C~08:00", "-1,8° C~"]`. Now I must split the rest of the array but not the first one. How? :)

Comment: @Barmar Yes. I know that. I want to extract the time and the temperature 13 hours into the future and use this to the chart.

Comment: Your first split is correct. You need to loop over all the results, splitting each on `^`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.map`:

```
var time_and_temp = time.map(function(el) {
    var temp = el.split('^');
    return { time: temp[0], temperature: temp[1] };
});
```

This will set `time_and_temp` to an array like:

```
[ { time: "19:00",
    temperature: "-2,2° C"
  },
  { time: "20:00",
    temperature: "-2° C"
  }
  ...
]
```

Comment: Thank you! But how can I insert the output (which I suppose will be extracted with `time_and_temp[0]` for the first row) into the chart? Should I put a `for` loop around the chart?

Comment: I don't know what your chart expects. You can use `time_and_temp[0].time` to get the time, and `time_and_temp[0].temperature` to get the temperature.

Comment: You can find everything about how the chart works by clicking on the link in my question. But to tell the long story short: `labels` prints the time and `data` prints the temperature. Your variable only prints the time and the temperature one time. Therefore I must use a `for` loop but I don't know where I should put it. Around the chart (`for(...) { lineChartData = { ... } }`)?

Answer (score 0):

`yr16 = yr[16].toString();`

`time = yr16.split('^')[0];`

`temp = yr16.split('^')[1];`

You need to include `[0]` and `[1]` after `.split('^')` to indicate which part (before or after `^`) is being assigned to the variable.